# BerryBoot - Restart loop - Check your switch settings

Tags: raspberry-pi

[image]

I´m trying to install BerryBoot on a Raspberry Pi 3 but I only get this error up.

> Flow control seems to be disabled on your Ethernet switch. This can
>   cause network performance problems on the Pi 3+. If possible change
>   your switch settings to enable flow control.

When pressing close and Ok the Pi 3 restarts and then the error appear again. I´ve also tried to install different version of BerryBoot. When trying to enable wifi the pi restart.

Answer (score 1):

Think this can be related to wrong power supply :/